# webmethods IS pub.client http not following http client standards?

Tags: webmethods

**The issue:** Webmethods HTTP client is calling the wrong endpoint on my Apache server configured with multiple virtual hosts, based on DNS.

**What I think is happening:** I think Webmethods HTTP client may be looking up the IP address and using that to perform HTTP operations instead of using the DNS name, which is causing the Apache server to identify it as a request to the main virtual server, not the desired one.

**Question**: So, how can I make webmethods use the DNS name instead of the IP?  Is my theory about the Webmethods HTTP client correct?  As far as I can tell this is a very non-standard approach to HTTP Client design.

Here is how it is configured to help you better understand:

```
Apache ->
  host.example.com => /var/www/host/html
  host2.example.com => /var/www/host2/html
```

`curl -v http://host.example.com` and `curl -v http://host2.example.com` appropriately return documents from their respective directories.

Configuring `pub.client:http` with `http://host2.example.com` causes the webmethods IS server to request `http://host.example.com` documents (obviously leading to a 404: Not Found).

*Note that obviously the system is not returning documents like HTML but rather serving dynamic content.*

Comment: Since this is meant to be a direct HTTP proxy, I'm trying to send all request headers through untouched.  It looks like when I don't "pass through" the HTTP headers it performs as expected, calling the appropriate endpoint.

Comment: The `host` header will be used to identify the specific sub domain to use, see https://superuser.com/questions/234292/how-is-a-subdomain-passed-to-the-webserver. Please [edit] your question to include the complete HTTP request used by webmethods as well as the complete HTTP request used by `curl`.

Comment: @Progman you nailed it - the Host header was being set to "localhost" by curl and we were passing that through.  Now just need to figure out how to tell webmethods not to do that...

Answer (score 1):

The comment from Progman is the clue here - basically in order to direct Apache to call your virtual server, the `Host` header must be given with the expected value.  In my example, that would be `Host: host2.example.com`.  I was having webmethods IS copy over the headers exactly like I was posting them from curl, and it was sending `Host: localhost:5555` over to my proxied server.  I simply created a pipeline Map operation and hardcoded it and it is working fine now.

The oddity to me seems to be that pub.client:http didn't auto-set the Host header for me based on the 'url' value, which is what I would have expected.